# Javascript remove div space usage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I have this tabbedpage, but the content that isn't visible still uses the space, so all the divs are below each other. I want the space usage to be gone, but still want the animation I created. Here is the snippet:

```js
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-indicator")[0];
let tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-content")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(let i=0;i<tabsPane.length;i++){
    tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");
    
    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 2) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

```css
.tabbedpage {
    padding: 20px 0px;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header {
  height:60px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header > div {
  width:calc(100% / 2);
  text-align:center;
  color:#888;
  font-weight:600;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  outline:none;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header > div > i {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header > div.active {
  color:#d81e05;
  display: block;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-indicator {
  position:relative;
  width:calc(100% / 2);
  height:5px;
  background:#d81e05;
  left:0px;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content {
  position:relative;
  height:calc(100% - 60px);
  padding:10px 5px;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content > div {
  top:-200%;
  opacity:0;
  transform:scale(0.9);
  transition:opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms,
    transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content > div.active {
  top:0px;
  opacity:1;
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbedpage">
  <div class="tabbedpage-header">
    <div class="active">
      Statistics
    </div>
    <div>
      User management
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabbedpage-indicator"></div>
  <div class="tabbedpage-content">
    <div class="active">
      <h2>This is statistics section</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error neque saepe commodi blanditiis fugiat nisi aliquam ratione porro quibusdam in, eveniet accusantium cumque. Dolore officia reprehenderit perferendis quod libero omnis.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>This is sser management section</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi minus exercitationem vero, id autem fugit assumenda a molestiae numquam at, quisquam cumque. Labore eligendi perspiciatis quia incidunt quaerat ut ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove the space that the hidden div is using, but still have the fade in animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `opacity` to hide the `div`, Which means the `div` will not be hidden, But it will be `invisible`. So the space of the `div` will be there.

Using **display** will remove animation.

Let's play with **position**, overlap both `div` using `position: absolute` and control the visibility using `opacity`.

See the code below.

```js
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-indicator")[0];
let tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-content")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(let i=0;i<tabsPane.length;i++){
    tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");
    
    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 2) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

```css
.tabbedpage {
    padding: 20px 0px;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header {
  height:60px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header > div {
  width:calc(100% / 2);
  text-align:center;
  color:#888;
  font-weight:600;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  outline:none;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header > div > i {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header > div.active {
  color:#d81e05;
  display: block;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-indicator {
  position:relative;
  width:calc(100% / 2);
  height:5px;
  background:#d81e05;
  left:0px;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content {
  position:relative;
  height:calc(100% - 60px);
  padding:10px 5px;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  opacity:0;
  transform:scale(0.9);
  transition:opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms,
    transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content > div.active {
  opacity:1;
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbedpage">
  <div class="tabbedpage-header">
    <div class="active">
      Statistics
    </div>
    <div>
      User management
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabbedpage-indicator"></div>
  <div class="tabbedpage-content">
    <div class="active">
      <h2>This is statistics section</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error neque saepe commodi blanditiis fugiat nisi aliquam ratione porro quibusdam in, eveniet accusantium cumque. Dolore officia reprehenderit perferendis quod libero omnis.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>This is sser management section</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi minus exercitationem vero, id autem fugit assumenda a molestiae numquam at, quisquam cumque. Labore eligendi perspiciatis quia incidunt quaerat ut ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but now the animation is gone. I still want to use the animation

Comment: **@A.Vreeswijk** I updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Now I got another problem xD, because it is a absolute layout, the content of the tabbedpage goes trough the footer of my page?

Comment: I cannot deal with the layout without your whole code. Still you can control the overflow.